# class methods or static variable, what's the difference?

Tags: objective-c, static, class-method

i'm a bit lost with the class methods, and "static" variables : what is the difference? for example, in a script with a mapView, we have this :

> +(CGFloat)annotationPadding;
>   {
>       return 10.0f;
>   }

Why do we use this class method instead of a static variable, if the only we want is "the same value for that class" ?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: This looks like a property, maybe that's the reason, to keep in line with the property pattern?

Comment: Oh, and maybe thought 'this could change later to become a computation', or it was one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class method is to a static variable what an instance method is to an instance variable.

One is a method that can do processing, the other is a variable that can hold - or point to - data.

You'd use a class method for convenience usage like e.g. `NSMutableArray` does with the `array` class method, or for processing that doesn't require the object's state to do the task.

Comment: thanks mortenfast, i'm sorry i'm not sure to understand your example, like what kind of processing should we expect from a class method? thanks

Comment: @Paul Any kind. :) An instance method on an object usually depends on the object's instance variables to do its processing. A class method is normally used when a method can stand on its own without having to know about a specific object's state. Class methods are often used to construct objects of the class' type, but they're not limited to doing just that.